# Javascript - Find twitter short url from tweet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a jquery code to find the url part from a tweet and alert it. I have this tweet wrapped inside a div with a class .tweet

> some tweet text goes here https://t.co/CTyPa0sYmp

I tried Regx expression but I guess because of the uppercase in url, it can only find the beginning of it.

```
var searchText = jQuery('.tweet').text(),
urls = searchText.match(/\b(https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/i);
alert(urls);
```

but the code only alerts "https://t.co"

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7kR/312/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gd7kR/314/ The regex is wrong. I did a match for all. This is not a perfect answer. But, thats what you are missing.

Comment: Add `\/\w+` to last capture group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied the following regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url), should work in your case. And I'm marking this question as duplicate.

```
/\b((http|https)?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})\b/ig
```

Comment: Thank a lot Ammar. Sorry that it's a duplicate coz sometimes it's very urgent and you don't get enough time to do proper research.

Comment: No issues brother :) all the best